# How to convert prc to pdf in Ubuntu cli?

Tags: pdf, conversion

Is there any CLI tool, that can convert a (Mobipocket eBook) PRC file to a PDF?

I Googled on it but all I found was about converting doc(x)/HTML/series of images to pdf.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is using `calibre` via command line, though I haven't tried this myself. PRC/EPUB/AZW is basically a bunch of HTML files in a compressed archieve, so you *do* need to render this HTML somehow.

Comment: I tried Calibre but the problem with it was it couldn't be installed without GUI which I don't need since I don't have X11 installed on my home server. If there's no other option, I will install Calibre on my Windows PC and not on my server.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested `ebook-convert` from Calibre, and it runs completely without X11 from the commandline. Of course the package as a whole depends on X11 and other GUI libraries. If you don't want to install those (or if you don't want to use `dpkg --force-depends -i ...`, and then manually sort out what you still need), the only way is to get the source, figure out what parts you need, and install those.

There's also `wkhtmltopdf`, but again this relies on Qt libraries to do the rendering, and I'm nor sure how well it works with ebooks: I didn't try, and you'll have to unpack the PRC file first.

If you want to render graphics (and converting HTML into a PDF means you *have* to render graphics, you need to do glyph positioning) *some* kind of graphics libraries are unavoidable ...

Comment: I've managed to extract ebook-convert from calibre, to use it on a headless/server machine: https://askubuntu.com/a/1453851/182054